# How to upload Video on Twitter using Twitvid in iPhone application programmatically

Tags: ios, ios4

How to upload Video on Twitter using Twitvid in iPhone application through programming?

Comment: please see my question here and help me whats problem with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066213/how-to-upload-video-on-twitter-using-twitvid-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have code that I can give you, and I don't know of a library that does all that easily, but I'd suggest you to look over the TwitVid documentation: http://twitvid.pbworks.com/w/page/22556295/FrontPage

To accomplish doing the required OAuth requests, I suggest you use the ASIFormDataRequest class: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: please see my question here and help me whats problem with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066213/how-to-upload-video-on-twitter-using-twitvid-in-iphone-sdk