# Post video on twitter using twitVid

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on application in which i have to post video on twitter, i am using twitvid classes which i got from http://twitvid.pbworks.com/w/page/22556313/Twitvid%C2%A0API%C2%A0Method%3A%C2%A0upload,
but there is no login process.
I am using MGTwitterEngine and SAOAuthTwitterEnginee Classes for Login Process and TwitVid Classes for post video. but i am not able to login, when i open modal it show me your Token is not right.(like eror)

But if i am using same Token after removing twitvid classes then it works fine, i am able to login.

Plz advice me what to do for post video on twitter.
Thaanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785784/how-to-upload-video-on-twitter-using-twitvid-in-iphone-application-programmitica